# Get list of SQL instances from another (trusted) network

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building an application which interacts with SQL server data.

At the start of the application, I populate a ComboBox with a list of available SQL servers.

My issue is that the application needs to access the SQL servers on a separate domain (basically the network of a company that has been bought by the company I work for).

So my question is, is there any way to get a list of SQL servers available on another network by passing credentials through the code to get the list of SQL servers?

On my work machine, I have entered the relevant credentials into Windows Credentials Manager, which allows me to access these SQL Servers through SQL Server Management Studio using the fully qualified server name e.g. SQLSERVER1.ourdomainname.com

This is the code I have written to populate the ComboBox, which is working fine for servers on my local network.

```
string sqlServers = Environment.MachineName;
DataTable servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();

for (int i = 0; i < servers.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (sqlServers == servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString())
    {
        if ((servers.Rows[i]["InstanceName"] as string) != null)
            comboSqlServers.Items.Add(servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"] + @"\" + servers.Rows[i]["InstanceName"]);
        else
            comboSqlServers.Items.Add(servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your local system might not have access to grant those servers. You can deploy the code on the server and test it. Add the logs to know the errors.

Comment: The `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` uses broadcast packets to enumerate the instances from listening SQL Browser services, that's why it only returns instances on the local network. Ref: [Enumerating Instances of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enumerating-instances-of-sql-server)

Comment: There are a number of different methods to get a list of instances. Try take  look at DbaTools' Powershell Module, the `Find-DbaInstance` function https://docs.dbatools.io/Find-DbaInstance and see source code

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, I will take a look. Still new to programming, so every day I'm learning more

Answer (score 0):

I've decided not to try and implement this. I will instead make a stipulation that the app only works on one domain at a time. It is highly unlikely this will cause an issues given what the app is going to be used for.